# This selector AND element within this selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to include both: `$(this)` and `$("h3", this)` in the same line?

Maybe something like `$("h3,", this)`?

I know that's not right but I've never heard of the equivalent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`.andSelf` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/):

```
$(this).find('h3').andSelf()
```

It merges the previously selected elements in the stack (`$(this)`) with the current selection (`$(this).find('h3')`).